# Where is Emmets snippets.json?

Tags: aptana, aptana3, emmet

Where can I find the snippets.json for emmet, running it as a plugin for Aptana Studio 3?

I have found the menu entries in the preferences window, but I want to edit existing snippets not create new ones.

Comment: Is there an entry under Commands > Emmet > Edit this Bundle?

Comment: Simply create snippet with the same to override default one.

Comment: @SarahKemp I'm not using the bundle version, thanks though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Aptana, Emmets snippets.json is within it's signed jar file, so editing it is kinda out of the question. What you CAN do, is extract it (or get it directly from Git @ https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/master/lib/snippets.json), see which abbreviations/snippets you'd like to change, then use Emmets GUI interface in Aptana to add your own using the same names as the defaults you wish to override.

This allows you to customise how each snippet/abbreviations acts without having to bugger around the file system.